# nested structure array in c

Tags: c

how do I place an array of structures inside another structure to be able to access them all?

```
struct fruit {
    float price;
    int supplyId;
    int deliveryTime;
};

struct fruits {
    struct fruit *item[3];
};

struct fruit banana [3] = {
    {1.35, 17, 5},
    {1.27, 3, 3},
    {2.00, 13, 1},
};

struct fruit apple [3] = {
    {2.15, 11, 5},
    {1.90, 2, 7},
    {1.00, 7, 12}, 
};

struct fruits fruits1 [2] = {
    {banana},
    {apple},
};

int main()
{
    printf("%f",fruits1[0].item[0]->price);
    return 0;
}
```

in this example, I first price in banana structure, but how do I get 2nd?

I can do it like this:

```
struct fruits fruits1 [2] = {
    {banana,&banana[1],&banana[2]},
    {apple,&apple[1],&apple[2]},
};
```

but is there a better way to do it?

Comment: C and C++ are very different languages. Please don't tag both unless you are specifically asking about their differences.

Comment: C and C++ are 2 different languages. Please only add 1 tag to your question.

Comment: You are likely to make the code hard to follow  with the similar names `struct fruit` and `struct fruits`. If the second contains the first, then `struct basket` or sth would be clearer. Similarly with `fruits1`, it could be `basket shopping[2]`.

Comment: It would look more consistent if you changed `banana,` to `&banana[0],` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> in this example, I first price in banana structure, but how do I get 2nd?

You can use the subscirpt operator to access siblings of the pointed element:

```
printf("%f", fruits1[0].item[0][1].price);
```

---

It's somewhat unclear, why you have an array of 3 pointers:

> ```
> struct fruits {
>     struct fruit *item[3];
> };
> ```

But you only initialise one of the pointers (rest will be null):

> ```
> struct fruits fruits1 [2] = {
>     {banana},
> ```

Comment: thank you, it's working!!! :)

I tried it like this before:
 fruits1[0].item[0][1]->price
this didn't work :P